# How to use nosetest to find coverage of non-tested Python files?

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

The `nosetests` tool for Python testing has an option `--cover-inclusive` to include all files to be able to discover holes in testing (see [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html#cover-code-coverage)). However, it does not seem to work properly: it does not display files with 0% coverage at all, whereas just running the `coverage` tool instead of `nosetests` does do the job.

Here is a minimal example folder structure to reproduce the issue:

```
__init__.py
foobar/__init__.py
foobar/foo.py       # Has one function
foobar/bar.py       # Has one function
test_bar.py         # Tests only the function in foobar/bar.py
```

When running this with `nosetests` I get the following result:

```
$ nosetests --cover-package=foobar --with-coverage --cover-inclusive
Name                 Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------------
foobar/__init__.py       0      0   100%
foobar/bar.py            2      0   100%
----------------------------------------
TOTAL                    2      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does not display the missing tests for `foobar/foo.py`. However, running `coverage` directly does do the job:

```
$ coverage run --source=. --omit=test* -m unittest discover && coverage report
Name                 Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------------
__init__.py              0      0   100%
foobar/__init__.py       0      0   100%
foobar/bar.py            2      0   100%
foobar/foo.py            2      2     0%
----------------------------------------
TOTAL                    4      2    50%
```

This behavior of `nosetests` doesn't change when removing the `--cover-inclusive` option. The only way I've found to include `foobar/foo.py` is to set `--cover-package=.`, but that then displays all other files from includes as well.

Is this `--cover-inclusive` option broken or am I doing something wrong? How do I get the same output as shown above from `coverage run` but then with `nosetests`?

Comment: Nose is not maintained, so issues have been creeping in for a while.  It's likely a bug.